# Regex match in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex like this

```
r"^(.*?),(.*?)(,.*?=.*)"
```

And a string like this

> name1,value1,tag11=value11,tag12=value12,tag13=value13

I am trying to check, using a regex, whether the string follows the following format: `name,value`, name and value pairs separated by commas.

I need then to extract the comma-separated data using a regex.

I am getting the data extracted as a first group as name1 and a second group as value2 and a third group matches completely from tag11 to value13 (due to greedy match).

But I want to match each name and value pairs. I am new to Python and not sure how can I achieve this.

Comment: Regex like the following might be helpful: `((?<name>\w+),(?<value>\w+))|(?<name>\w+)=(?<value>\w+)` (tested on RegExr sans the named capture groups).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out Python doesn't support repeated named capture groups unlike .NET, which is a bit of a shame (means my solution is a little longer than I thought it'd need to be). Does this meet your requirements?

```
import re

def is_valid(s):
    pattern = '^name\d+,value\d+(,tag\d+=value\d+)*$'
    return re.match(pattern, s)

def get_name_value_pairs(s):
    if not is_valid(s):
        raise ValueError('Invalid input: {}'.format(s))

    pattern = '((?P<name1>\w+),(?P<value1>\w+))|(?P<name2>\w+)=(?P<value2>\w+)'
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, s):
        name1 = match.group('name1')
        name2 = match.group('name2')
        value1 = match.group('value1')
        value2 = match.group('value2')

        if name1 and value1:
            yield name1, value1
        elif name2 and value2:
            yield name2, value2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testString = 'name1,value1,tag11=value11,tag12=value12,tag13=value13'
    assert not is_valid('')
    assert not is_valid('foo')
    assert is_valid(testString)

    print(list(get_name_value_pairs(testString)))
```

**Output**

```
[('name1', 'value1'), ('tag11', 'value11'), ('tag12', 'value12'), ('tag13', 'value13')]
```

**Edit 1**

Added input validation logic. Assumptions made:

- Must have initial name/value pair in form `name<x>,value<x>`
- All following pairs must be in form `tag<x>=value<x>`
- Names and values consist only of alphanumeric characters
- Whitespace is not allowed

Note that I'm not currently validating that *x* is the same value within a name/value pair, which I assume is a requirement. I'm <s>not sure how to do this</s> leaving this as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: your solution helps me but i need to validate the format of the string. it should be in the format as name1, value1, tag-1=value-1, tag-2=value-2 ... tag-n=value-n. how can i achieve this.

Comment: @MohanRaj I've added validation logic. I don't really understand what you're doing so I've made assumptions about what exactly determines if a string is valid or not, but I've listed my assumptions and you can tweak as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just split by the commas:

```
s = 'name1,value1,tag11=value11,tag12=value12,tag13=value13'
print(s.split(','))
```

If you want to use regex it's just as simple using the pattern:

```
[^,]+
```

Example:

https://regex101.com/r/jS6fgW/1

Answer (score 1):

First, validate the format acc. to your pattern, and then split with `[,=]` regex (that matches `,` and `=`) and convert to a dictionary like this:

```
import itertools, re
s = 'name1,value1,tag11=value11,tag12=value12,tag13=value13'
if re.match(r'[^,=]+,[^,=]+(?:,[^,=]+=[^,=]+)+$', s):
    l = re.split("[=,]", s)
    d = dict(itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(l)] * 2, fillvalue=""))
    print(d)
else:
    print("Not valid!")
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Cv4wmF)

The [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/dXM1UG/1) is

```
^[^,=]+,[^,=]+(?:,[^,=]+=[^,=]+)+$
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string (in the `re.match`, this can be omitted since the pattern is already anchored)
- `[^,=]+` - 1+ chars other than `=` and `,`
- `,`  - a comma
- `[^,=]+` - 1+ chars other than `=` and `,`
- `(?:,[^,=]+=[^,=]+)+` - 1 or more sequences of:

  - `,` - comma
  - `[^,=]+` - 1+ chars other than `=` and `,`
  - `=` - an equal sign
  - `[^,=]+` - 1+ chars other than `=` and `,`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: it helps me but i also need to validate the format of the input string. it should be in the format as name1, value1, tag-1=value-1, tag-2=value-2 ... tag-n=value-n. how can i achieve this.

Comment: You need to precise: can the comma separated `name,value` appear somewhere inside the string, or at its end? Maybe [`^(?:\w+[=,]\w+)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/qjH6UA/1) is enough and will do? Or if you really have a single comma-separated name-value at the start and then `=`-separated ones, use [`^[^,=]+,[^,=]+(?:,[^,=]+=[^,=]+)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/dXM1UG/1).

Comment: It should be only at the beginning of the string.